# Javascript : Append data from array to another function

Tags: javascript, html

I have function to load all post like :

```
function testfn(json) {

.........
for(i=0; i<post.length; i++)
{
....
       if ((i >= 0) && (i<6)) {
            a3 += '<p><a href="'+links[c]+'">'+posttitle+'</a></p>';
          }
}
 document.write(a3);
}
```

And here is to call function testfn :

```
var as = document.getElementById('category').getElementsByTagName('a');
        var links = [];
        for (var c = 0; c < as.length; c++) {
          links[c] = /[^/]*$/.exec(as[c].href);
          document.write('<script src=\"/feeds/posts/default/-/'+links[c]+'?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=testfn&max-results=5\"><\/script>');
```

`Links[c]` is catch from `category` ID. I now want call post from `category` by for each, also append links[c] to post content.

I add `link[c]` to a element like :

```
<a href="'+links[c]+'">'+posttitle+'</a>
```

But it is undefined. How can I add `link[c]` to `a` element.

Example:

```
<div id="category">
    <p> <a href="../categoryone">One</a> </p>
    <p> <a href="../categorytwo">Two</a> </p>
  </div>
```

After catch links from category `ID` i have two categories are: `categoryone` and `categorytwo`.

Then, call data from each category (using for loop) and also add `categoryone` to `a link` after one loop be end.

It means after call I have HTML of posts lik:

```
<p><a href="categoryone">This is categoryone</a></p>
<p><a href="categorytwo">This is categorytwo</a></p>
```

Thanks for all helps.

Comment: Clarify where you start and how the end result should look like?

Comment: Try to remove 'var' from the links line. so you have links=[];  it's possible you have a variable scope issue, but i'm not sure

Comment: one loop load only category. Number of categories is limit

Comment: Do not use document.write